# Not able to upload contract in substrate node template

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, pallet-contracts

I have added `pallet-contract` in [our chain](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate). Build contract works fine and run chain in dev mode also works fine. But when I try to deploy contract it doesn't work and doesn't throw any error. Can someone please help me.

[image]

This issue on inspect
[image]

I try to directly use the Runtime Call and still it doesn't work?

[image]

This is [github repo](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate)

Comment: what's the error you are facing?

Comment: no error just loading

Comment: Are the rest of the extrinsics working? (from other pallets)

Comment: yes everything working fine just I am not able to upload contract @AlexBean

Comment: I was able to replicate it, I could upload a contract with contracts-ui and cargo-contracts but is giving me the same error with PolkadotJS UI. It looks like an issue with PolkadotJS

Comment: I opened an issue in the repo: https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5698

Comment: You could use substrate-contracts-node

Comment: @Bruno I wan't to upload contract in my own chain and pay transaction fee in my own token

Answer (score 1):

While the PolkadotJs issue is being resolved (see comments), you can use cargo contract cli to build, upload, instantiate, and call:

- https://use.ink/cargo-contract-cli

Another option that I see is to directly use the Runtime Call:

[image]

Comment: now I wan't to test for `chain_extension` and for this I have to use `pallet_contract` configuration and upload smart contract in mychain but with this issue I am not able to move further.

Comment: In my answer I gave you two options that should allow you to move further. Give them a shot..

Comment: I have tried to upload code Runtime Call but I get the issue I have posted screenshot in my question.

Comment: You uploaded a new screenshot, so there is something wrong with your contract. Try uploading the Flipper contract and see if that works.

Comment: that is `Flipper Contract` I just changed name of contract to `myapp` while creating new contract

Comment: instead of polkadotjs what I am doing right now testing contract until [this issue fixed](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5698) is using [polkadotjs-app](https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/#/accounts)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using polkadotjs what I am doing right now is testing contract until [this issue fixed](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5698) is using [polkadotjs-app](https://polkadotjs-apps.web.app/#/accounts)